# OnClick button to refresh textbox not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code in the code behind. Goal is to reset the value of the `textbox` to blank. When I click the `button`, however, nothing happens.

```
protected void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label srch_Title = (Label)FindControl("srch_Title");
    srch_Title.Text = String.Empty;
}
```

Here is the `textbox` code from the main page:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="srch_Title" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" />
```

Here is the button code from the main page:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnResetSearch" runat="server" OnClick="btnReset_Click" Height="35px" Text="Reset Search" Width="120px" />
```

I am a novice / enthusiast programmer and this is my first post. Guessing the problem is obvious and I am just not seeing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out by adding another FindControl. First FindControl referred to the master and used the results of that to setup a second FindControl pointed at the text box. I did not post enough code when I asked the original question as  I think an experienced programmer would have quickly spotted the solution. Thanks to all who contributed.

Answer (score 0):

You should define your control as TextBox not Label  , like this :

```
TextBox srch_Title = (TextBox )Form.FindControl("srch_Title");
srch_Title.Text = String.Empty;
```

Comment: Entered this code however the textbox is still retaining the characters I am trying to clear from it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the `srch_Title` control as a `TextBox` instead of as a `Label`, like this:

```
// The as operator avoids a cast exception, 
// returns null if cast cannot be successfully performed
TextBox theSrchTitleTextBox = Form.FindControl("srch_Title") as TextBox;

// Verify that we found the text box before we try to use it,
// to avoid null reference exception
if(theSrchTitleTextBox != null)
{
    theSrchTitleTextBox.Text = String.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Entered this code but the textbox is still retaining the values I am trying to clear from it.

Comment: If you put a break point on the line `theSrchTitleTextBox.Text = String.Empty;` and then step past it, what is the value of `theSrchTitleTextBox.Text`?

Comment: Thank you Karl for the help. However, appears there is no value. Autos is blank. Message when mouse hovers over theSrchTitleTextBox.Text is "string TextBox.Text Gets or sets the text content......" Does not appear it is ever getting to the function as the red dot stays red, yellow arrow does not show up, etc., even if I click on the button.

Comment: Try removing the `AutoPostBack="true"` from the `TextBox` control in the markup, does that change anything?

Comment: I tried that earlier and it did not change anything with regard to how the button functioned but it did stop the text box from working like it needs to.